# iPhone Compile Architecture: Standard vs Optimized

Tags: iphone, xcode, architecture, compilation

This is something stupid I probably should know, but Googling fails me:

When compiling the binary I'm going to submit to the App Store, in the Project Info -> Build tab, there's an "Architectures" option. The default is "Standard" but I noticed there is also "Optimized"

Which should I use when submitting to the app store? I have been using Standard all along w/ my ad hoc testing...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimized will run somewhat faster on the 3Gs.  If you like you can check that and test a bit on the 3Gs, just to make sure all is well.